# Moved logs to ram (tmpfs) and now got this problem

Tags: flash, log, tmpfs

I have installed ubuntu server on flash and have done a few things to minimise writes to disk. One of the things I have done is to direct a number of directories to ram via tmpfs. You can see how I have things set up below:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1              1290072   1228448         0 100% /
udev                   3990268         8   3990260   1% /dev
tmpfs                  4032204         0   4032204   0% /tmp
tmpfs                  1612884       296   1612588   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                   4032204         0   4032204   0% /run/shm
tmpfs                  4032204         0   4032204   0% /var/tmp
tmpfs                  4032204       564   4031640   1% /var/log
tmpfs                  4032204        16   4032188   1% /var/log/apt
/dev/md127           3845715976  35833316 3809882660   1% /massiveData
/dev/sde6              2401840     82872   2196960   4% /home
```

I received an email from my system saying the following. Anyone know what I should do to fix this?

```
/etc/cron.daily/man-db:
/usr/bin/mandb: can't write to /var/cache/man/5766: No space left on device
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/man-db exited with return code 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just trying to update the manpage databases (used for `apropos` etc). These aren't very important, you can ignore them / disable the cronjob.

The contents of `/var/cache` should always be safe to delete.

Answer (score 2):

You sort of have two issues.

First your root partition, `/dev/sde1` is full. This is the source of your error message (not tmpfs).

You should make space either by deleting necessary files or enlarging the partition. You can make some space with

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Second, if you wish, you could mount /var/cache in tmpfs ;)

Comment: Thanks. I have been struggling to increase the size of root all day. I want to shrink home and increase root but parted tells me it can not shrink home. Facing a rebuild here :(

Comment: You should manage your partitions with a live CD, you can not resize partitions while they are in use.

Comment: i was booted from a different drive when i was trying to change partition sizes.

Comment: Hard to know with what little information you posted. Sometimes you need to resize in steps, sometimes you need to somewhat move your partitions.